# Eclipse non-blocking completion ignored

Tags: eclipse, content-assist

I my Eclipse java content assist settings I see the warning that "the non-blocking completion will be ignored because the following contributions require the UI Thread:"

I unchecked the proposal kinds which seem to be belong to the offending packages, in both panels, and restarted the Eclipse, but the warning is sill there.

What can be done to not ignore the non-blocking setting?

The content assist works currently not that bad (by Eclipse standards), so I wonder whether the non-blocking assist wasn't actually disabled and this warning is false?

[image: dialog screenshot]

Comment: No, this warning is not false: disabling is not enough, you would have to uninstall these plugins to be able to use this new option. Non-blocking completion does not speed-up the calculation of the proposals, but you can continue typing even when the calculation of some proposals takes longer. If you do not have such cases, you do not need this option.

Comment: I actually do have blocking of the UI when the proposals are being recalcualted, especially when trying to backspace some characters in the function name and get a freeze for several seconds on each character - happens all the time, at least used to on 2019-06 version. Thanks.

Comment: In the 2020-09 release next week all Eclipse proposals except the JPA JPQL proposals have been improved to run in a non-UI thread (see https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=563158#c5). Do you need the _Dali Java Persistence Tools_ (which contributes the JPA JPQL proposals)? If not, you can uninstall it and use this new option.